# When you should use SparseArray setValueAt()?

Tags: android

Why is `setValueAt(...)` in the public interface of the `SparseArray` class? I was using it instead of `put(...)` obviously not getting the result I had in mind.

Comment: What's the difference between your expectation and reality?

Comment: I thought it was supposed to be what put() does

Comment: No. `put()` maps the value with the provided **key**, where as `setValueAt()` maps the value with the provided **index**.

Comment: Yeah.. I got that, but when someone will want to use the index directly?

Comment: May be for, first or last position.  Though it doesn't matter, but still.

Answer (score 1):

I came here trying to figure out the same thing. As Prekak Sola mentioned in the comments, `setValueAt` maps a value on a specific **index**, while `put` maps a value on a specific **key**.

Obviously, that can become confusing, but I think it is a very useful feature, because if you look at the official [SparseArray documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html), it is mentioned that the `SparseArray` is generally slower than a `HashMap`, because *lookups require a binary search and adds and removes require inserting and deleting entries in the array*.

So, I guess that in certain cases, it would perform much faster if you *iterate over the items in this container using [keyAt(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html#keyAt(int)), [size()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html#size())*, and obviously all **index-related** functions, such as `setValueAt`, instead of using the keys.